# AngularJS on condition ng-if show SAVE and UPDATE BUTTON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form novalidate>
    <label>Name</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newcontact.name" required/>
    <label>Email</label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newcontact.email" required/>
    <label>Phone</label> 
        <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="newcontact.phone" required/>
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="newcontact.id" />

     <input type="button" ng-if="newcontact.id" value="UPDATE" ng-click="saveContact()" />
     <input type="button" ng-if="!newcontact.id" value="SAVE" ng-click="updateContact()" />
    </form>
```

Consider the above form, In this create/edit is using the same template, So i like to show 
Button names as 'UPDATE' or 'SAVE' based on newcontact.id value.

Need to concentrate only on these :

```
<input type="button" ng-if="newcontact.id" value="UPDATE" ng-click="saveContact()" />
         <input type="button" ng-if="!newcontact.id" value="SAVE" ng-click="updateContact()" />
```

Since angular do not have ng-else, so how to achieve this.

Also need to know.
2. how you secure business logic from user in AngularJS

Comment: Unless I am missing the obvious, what you have looks good to me.

Answer (score 4):

Well,

you can just make use of `ng-show` here, by using a button instead:

```
<button ng-click="save()">
  <span ng-show="newcontact.id">Update</span>
  <span ng-show="!newcontact.id">Save</span>
</button>
```

with a save function that reacts to the state of `newcontact.id`:

```
angular.module('my.module').controller(['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.save = function() {
     if(typeof scope.newcontact.id === 'undefined') {
       // save
     } else {
       // update
     }
  }
}]);
```

EDIT: Another option could be not to decide once whether or not it's a new contact:

```
angular.module('my.module').controller(['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.newcontact = {};
   $scope.save = function() {
     /** Your save function */
   }
   // with a set contact, this will now always evaluate to 'Save'
   $scope.label = !!scope.newcontact.id ? 'Update' : 'Save';

   // so we go for something different:
   $scope.$watch('newcontact', function(newValue) {
     //this watches the newcontact for a change, 'newValue' is the new state of the scope property
     $scope.label = !!newValue.id ? 'Update' : 'Save';
   });
}]);
```

Note: That is just a crude example, you should probably use a service in conjunction with an API to save your users. what the example does is basically watching a scope property and changing the label accordingly. See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) for a more detailed description.

and then use it in the form:

```
<button ng-click="save()">{{label}}</button>
```

EDIT 2: To answer your question about hiding business logic from the user - you simply cannot. AngularJS is a JavaScript Framework and you give a users browser the full code to run your application. If you really have sensitive logic, put it on the server side and expose an interface to it (e.g. via JSON API).

Comment: +1 for second solution, since this gave me an idea how can be done, your $scope.label = !!scope.newcontact.id ? 'Update' : 'Save'; will not work says newcontact undefined,

Comment: thats what the `/** ... */` was for. You can basically either initialize the `newcontact` object if it is not present or prefill it, if it is present: `$scope.newcontact = {};` Gimme a minute, I put it in the code example.